# Prestashop product list exclude sold out

Tags: prestashop, smarty

I'd like to exclude from products list product that are sold out (they have quantity = 0). I've tried to modify foreach loop in product-list.tpl but it's not working the way it should. I've tried this:

```
{if $product.quantity_all_versions != 0}
```

Sold out product are hidden but instead of showing 21 product it shows for example 16, and count in pagination is wrong.

I think a better way is to modify $products variable. Where can i find it? Or maybe it will be better to modify sql query? Where can I find it?

//EDIT

I've changed the query:

```
$sql = 'SELECT p.*, product_shop.*, stock.out_of_stock, IFNULL(stock.quantity, 0) as quantity, MAX(product_attribute_shop.id_product_attribute) id_product_attribute, product_attribute_shop.minimal_quantity AS product_attribute_minimal_quantity, pl.`description`, pl.`description_short`, pl.`available_now`,
                    pl.`available_later`, pl.`link_rewrite`, pl.`meta_description`, pl.`meta_keywords`, pl.`meta_title`, pl.`name`, MAX(image_shop.`id_image`) id_image,
                    il.`legend`, m.`name` AS manufacturer_name, cl.`name` AS category_default,
                    DATEDIFF(product_shop.`date_add`, DATE_SUB(NOW(),
                    INTERVAL '.(Validate::isUnsignedInt(Configuration::get('PS_NB_DAYS_NEW_PRODUCT')) ? Configuration::get('PS_NB_DAYS_NEW_PRODUCT') : 20).'
                        DAY)) > 0 AS new, product_shop.price AS orderprice
                FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'category_product` cp
                LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'product` p
                    ON p.`id_product` = cp.`id_product`
                    AND p.`quantity` > 0
                '.Shop::addSqlAssociation('product', 'p').'
                LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'product_attribute` pa
                ON (p.`id_product` = pa.`id_product`)
                '.Shop::addSqlAssociation('product_attribute', 'pa', false, 'product_attribute_shop.`default_on` = 1').'
                '.Product::sqlStock('p', 'product_attribute_shop', false, $context->shop).'
                LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'category_lang` cl
                    ON (product_shop.`id_category_default` = cl.`id_category`
                    AND cl.`id_lang` = '.(int)$id_lang.Shop::addSqlRestrictionOnLang('cl').')
                LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'product_lang` pl
                    ON (p.`id_product` = pl.`id_product`
                    AND pl.`id_lang` = '.(int)$id_lang.Shop::addSqlRestrictionOnLang('pl').')
                LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'image` i
                    ON (i.`id_product` = p.`id_product`)'.
                Shop::addSqlAssociation('image', 'i', false, 'image_shop.cover=1').'
                LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'image_lang` il
                    ON (image_shop.`id_image` = il.`id_image`
                    AND il.`id_lang` = '.(int)$id_lang.')
                LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'manufacturer` m
                    ON m.`id_manufacturer` = p.`id_manufacturer`
                WHERE product_shop.`id_shop` = '.(int)$context->shop->id.'
                    AND cp.`id_category` IN('.implode(',',$cats_array).')'
                    .($active ? ' AND product_shop.`active` = 1' : '')
                    .($front ? ' AND product_shop.`visibility` IN ("both", "catalog")' : '')
                    .($id_supplier ? ' AND p.id_supplier = '.(int)$id_supplier : '')
                    .' GROUP BY product_shop.id_product';
```

I've added:

```
AND p.`quantity` > 0
```

And now on my site on product page there is no products displayed but when I run this SQL in PhpMyAdmin it's working. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the variable `$products` is assigned in `controllers/front/CategoryController.php` that uses `getProducts` function from `classes/Category.php`.

So, you need to edit SQL queries in `getProducts`. I don't know your exact version of Prestashop, but in 1.6 there are two queries and you should add something like

```
 AND IFNULL(stock.quantity, 0) > 0
```

to them.

You can also try [How to automatically disable out of stock products in PrestaShop](https://mypresta.eu/en/art/tips-and-tricks/how-to-disable-out-of-stock-product.html) that uses database tirggers.

Somebody even wrote a module [Hide out of stock products in Prestashop automatically – Free Prestashop module](http://prestashopaddon.com/download/prestashop-modules/hide-out-of-stock-products-in-prestashop-automatically-free-prestashop-module/). This is probably the easiest solution.

Comment: I don't know why it's not working on product page. Put your Prestashop in debug mode, maybe it'll display a detailed error message.

Comment: I've don it. There's no error only products list is empty.

Comment: Are you using blocklayered or blocklayered_mod module? Then you should open the `blocklayered.php` file and edit the function `getProductByFilters`. It's similar to `getProducts` just a bit more complicated.

Comment: Delete your ``AND p.`quantity` > 0`` in your `LEFT JOIN` clause. You need to add the code from my answer in the `WHERE` clause. Like so: ``WHERE IFNULL(stock.quantity, 0) > 0 AND product_shop.`id_shop` = '.(int)$context->shop->id.' ...``